# Create a standalone Java websocket client endpoint?

Tags: java, websocket, client

I want to create a websocket endpoint **client** in Java (as pure as possible, no frameworks), but virtually all the examples I have found have only server endpoints in Java, whereas the client is in Javascript. Can anyone point me to a good client example, or provide one?

Comment: Why do you care about websockets if your client is Java? Are you interfacing with an existing server which only provides a websocket API? And why no libraries?

Comment: That is correct, I want to connect to a websocket server. Libraries are fine, I just prefer to focus on core libraries, preferably from Oracle only, and not be adding a bunch of jars from some fly-by-night third party or random github developer unbacked by a major company.

Comment: User Tyrus a java web socket standalone client. - https://tyrus.java.net/

Comment: I nominate this question for re-opening since it is a Famous Question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure if this fits your criteria, but Jetty has a pretty clean client example here:

http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-websocket-client-api.html

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 10):

`@ClientEndpoint` annottation is part of the spec, so I'd suggest to use that,
here is a [good tutoria](https://www.openshift.com/blogs/how-to-build-java-websocket-applications-using-the-jsr-356-api)l , see step 4 and 6 .

**Step 6 from Openshift tutorial**

```
 @ClientEndpoint
public class WordgameClientEndpoint {

private static CountDownLatch latch;

private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());

@OnOpen
public void onOpen(Session session) {
    // same as above
}

@OnMessage
public String onMessage(String message, Session session) {
    // same as above
}

@OnClose
public void onClose(Session session, CloseReason closeReason) {
    logger.info(String.format("Session %s close because of %s", session.getId(), closeReason));
    latch.countDown();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    ClientManager client = ClientManager.createClient();
    try {
        client.connectToServer(WordgameClientEndpoint.class, new URI("ws://localhost:8025/websockets/game"));
        latch.await();

    } catch (DeploymentException | URISyntaxException | InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

}

in this example they are using [tyrus](https://tyrus.java.net/), which is the reference implementation for websockets in java, so I think that meets your requirement of a well backed websocket implementation.